# If I flip the normal on a backface, do I need to flip tangent and bitangent

Tags: normals

I have a mesh that is just a plane and need to be seen front and back.
In order to do light computation, on the back face I have to flip the normal, do I have to flip the Tangent and Bitangent?

It seems to me that I have to flip all of the three to keep the computation correct.

Comment: What results do you get when you test each way? Which approach looks correct for your situation?

Comment: Some mesh are correctly lighted on the back face, and some are flipped (like the light comes from the reverse-side). My engine got complicated too soon, I'm currently building a simplified model, as well as trying to do the computation on a paper.

Comment: If you're getting inconsistent results before you flip the tangent vectors, they'll still be inconsistent after you flip them (any that were already looking correct will now be incorrect), so it doesn't sound like this is the root of your problem. Want to update your question to describe the inconsistent lighting problem you're facing, to see if we can help you solve that first?